# Bookmarking web pages

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, web-application

I have some web pages which I'd like to take an eye on at home, not at work. 
The thing is my google chrome at work is not synchronized with my google chrome at home, so my bookmarks are not the same.

Currently I'm using the boring way which is : send my links by email and spam myself. I don't want to synchronize my google chrome because I don't want to have my home's bookmarks at work and my work's bookmarks at home.

Is there a web app or an intuitive way to get back my links once I'm at home?

Comment: I currently use OwnCloud's bookmarks feature, though you would need to setup an owncloud instance if you wanted to go down that route.

Comment: I would use two different chrome profiles.  This would allow you to launch specific profiles at both locations.  Chrome can sync bookmarks to Google Accounts.  Outside of that you have elminated your options for one reason or another.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes you're solution is really useful and easy to handle. Still thinking there is better way than remember two adresses, or sync, or email.. but maybe I'm really really too complicated and I'm gonna develop my own app haha :)

Comment: @So4ne - There is an easier way its called syncing all your bookmarks and putting work bookmarks in one folder and personal in another.  But you don't want that.  To be honest its not clear what you want.  You elminated most of your options.

Comment: @Ramhound please look at Alex's answer, that was that kind of app I was looking for :) but thank you for your help, didn't want it to be so tricky !

Comment: note you don't have to sync bookmarks, you can have chromes that do and others that don't.  Personally I use the tab syncing feature instead to look at content on different pc's, phones and tablets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can find what you want with "read-it-later" apps.

[Pocket](http://getpocket.com/) can do the job. Instead of saving bookmarks in Google Chrome you can use their [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-pocket/niloccemoadcdkdjlinkgdfekeahmflj?hl=fr) then visit all the websites later from another computer, smartphone or tablet.

That's what I use on work when I want to save a website in order to read it later at home.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

As Alex already said there's the excellent Pocket.

I personally use the Pocket Chrome extension (and Android app) to read the articles, and the old-named but effective [Readmine](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/readmine/jcakhdgcnblghphplknkbbneiapfgnej) extension to save the articles to Pocket from Chrome.

It gives you a useful "Read it later" option in the right click menu (everywhere on the page you want to save) and a saved articles counter on the extension icon.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try exporting bookmarks?

- Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
- Select Bookmarks.
- Select Bookmark manager.
- Click the Organize menu in the manager.
- Select Export bookmarks.
- Select a file to save bookmarks to (it will be saved in HTML format)

email file to yourself or store it on a flash drive

then import bookmarks when you need them:

- Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
- Select Bookmarks.
- Select Bookmark manager.
- Click the Organize menu in the manager.
- Select Import bookmarks.
- Browse to your previously saved HTML file

Comment: Thanks for your answer which could be a good alternative, but I'm not sure it's the efficient way, I should have to bookmark my page, export my page, then delete my bookmarks.

Comment: Ok, then look at another answer I have provided

Comment: @so4ne - You don't want to export them, you don't want to email yourself links, and you don't want to sync your bookmarks.  You have basically elminated all your options at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/about/features/sync_profiles). This product has a feature called sync profiles that does exactly what you requested.

> Xmarks gives you full control over which bookmarks are synced to which
>   computers. This allows you to:
>
> - Keep your private bookmarks at home, but sync everything else with your work computer.
> - Set up a different bookmark toolbar at home and at work, but sync everything else as you normally would.
> - Create a shortlist of bookmarks for when you access My Xmarks from your mobile phone.

Note that this product is propriety.

Comment: He doesn't want to sync his work bookmarks with his personal bookmarks.

Comment: @Ramhound Actually I think it could work, not sure I totally get it but I'm gonna try tonight at home :) Thanks !